# how Can I Use python dictionary to save graph edge weight

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

i want to save graph edge weight 
my input is something like this

```
[['A', 'B', '5']]
```

it means we have edge from 'A' to 'B' with weight 5

and my code is

```
def inputFormatter(array):

    Nodes={}

    for p in array:

        a=p[0]
        b=p[1]
        value=p[2]

        if(a not in Nodes):
            Nodes[a]=NodeInfo(a)

        if(b not in Nodes[a].neighbors):
            Nodes[a].neighbors[b]=value


        if(b not in Nodes):
            Nodes[b]=NodeInfo(b)

        if(a not in Nodes[b].neighbors):
            Nodes[b].neighbors[a]=value

    return Nodes
```

my NodeInfo Class is

```
class NodeInfo:

    neighbors={}
    nodeName=""

    def __init__(self, nodeName):
        self.nodeName=nodeName
```

but in printing neighbors key with this code

```
for node in Nodes:
    print node.nodeName +"\t"+ str(node.neighbors.keys())
```

i see this

```
A   ['A', 'B']
B   ['A', 'B']
```

why?
what's wrong?
How Can i Fix this?

Comment: How are you printing exactly?

Comment: printing code attched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `neighbors` are a class variable so they are shared in between instances. You should try:

```
class NodeInfo:
    def init(self, nodeName):
        self.nodeName = nodeName
        self.neighbors = {}
```

Note that you're overriding the class member `nodeName` with an instance member when you do `self.nodeName = nodeName` (which is why you don't see that they share it).